# Add "using" to ASPX or ASCX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Just out of curiosity...
Is there a way to add "using" to an ASPX/ASCX file?
eg. something like

```
<% using umbraco.NodeFactory; %>
```

So you can do

```
<%= Node.GetCurrent().Name %>
```

instead of

```
<%= umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().Name %>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for the [@Import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx).

At the top of the control or page (can be mixed and matched with other directives):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

Or (different placing of the @ character):

```
<% @Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```